# How can I create a snapshot of my web browser cache, allowing me to reset my environment to that cache

Tags: caching, browser-cache

I'm currently designing a test suite for ensuring are no caching issues in IE (and others, but mostly IE) when upgrading from the currently live version of a web app to the release candidate.

I'd be able to cut down on the runtime of the test significantly if I had a way of backing up my browser cache (with the previous release cache) and then resetting it after each test, rather than having to re-deploy the previous version and re-build the cache manually.

I could build an automated test to trawl through the web page and build the cache that way, but a faster / easier option may exist?